# Corona Object Properties

Tags: ios4, lua, coronasdk

I would like to find out if it is possible to get the custom properties of an object from its 2nd tier. An example is provided below which can be clearer than explaining in words.

```
objectA = display.newImage(...)
objectA.dmg = 100
objectA.firstBtn = display.newImage(...)
objectA.firstBtn.id = "firstBtn"
objectA.firstBtn:addEventListener("touch",touchHandler)

function touchHandler(event)
   -- I want to get the dmg of objectA
   -- I know that by calling event.target.id I can get "firstBtn" 
   -- but how do I get the dmg value like event.target.parent.dmg?
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot get the `objectA.dmg` in `event.target` even if you use `event.target.parent` you cannot get or access it. you can refer to this [link](http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/13940-modular-class-and-eventlisteners/) you have similar question on why you can't access it